# Laravel - how to return an array from a Model method?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Model method where I am trying to return a start and end date.

So like this:

```
public function start_end_date()
    {

        $instances = $this->hasMany(Instance::class, 'instance_id')
            ->where('instance_id', '=', $this->id)
            ->where('weekstart', '>=', time());

        $dates = $instances->pluck('weekstart')->toArray();
        $dates = array_map('strtotime', $dates);
        $startdate = min($dates);
        $enddate = strtotime("+7 day", max($dates));

        return array('startdate' => $startdate, 'enddate' => $enddate);
    }
```

In my view, I have `$courses` passed to the view. This object returns `courseinstances` via its model, as

```
 public function courseinstances()
    {

        return $this->hasMany(CcoursesInstance::class, 'course_id')
            ->where('startdate', '>=', time());
    }
```

So in view I can loop over $courses (e.g. @`foreach $courses as $course`) and also loop over instances (e.g. @`foreach $course->courseinstances as @instance`) and that works fine. For instance I can access some field or method-returned value as `$instance->somedata`

But in the view where I have `$course->courseinstances->start_end_date->startdate`

Laravel says

```
Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation (View:
```

I just can't figure out how Laravel wants me to return the start and end date and then reference it in the view. I don't want to pass separate variables to the view. I want to just use $courses as passed to the view and then drill down as I do for other pieces of data related to a course.

Ideas?

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 1):

`start_end_date` is not a property, it's a method so you need to declare it as a property, also `$instances` is returning a query builder instance and not a collection that you can pluck from, so append `get()` to actually retreive records

```php
public function getStartEndDateAttribute()
{
    $instances = $this->hasMany(Instance::class, 'instance_id')
                      ->where('instance_id', '=', $this->id)
                      ->where('weekstart', '>=', time())->get();
}
```

Comment: Without using get() the code still works (maybe because I am on Laravel 5.3). But just not sure syntax of the return statement that is needed and what referencing syntax I need to use in the view. Just read here https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators about Mutators, but seems to assume that you are referencing a column name. In my case, there is no column name, as I am generating the start and end date on the fly.

Comment: This is an accessor and doesn't relate to a column name, mutators begins with `set` instead of `get`

Comment: In the Laravel 5.3 doc, it says "To define an accessor, create a getFooAttribute method on your model where Foo is the "studly" cased name of the column you wish to access"  If I use function name getStart_end_dateAttribute(), and in view use  $instance->start_end_date['startdate'], the method is not being called.

Comment: Ok, have it figured out. Needed to rename function ```getStartEndDateAttribute()``` - thanks for helping me get this figured out!

Comment: The more I use this approach, the more I realize it is flawed, because on my backend I have angular controllers. Seems for these custom attributes to work in angular I need to use protected appends and that causes weird behavior (like the get attribute method being called when it shouldn't. So now I am back full circle and wondering how I could make a start_end_date() model method return the form of data needed so that in blade or angular controller I can access as ```$instance->start_end_date``` or in angular ```instance.start_end_date```

Answer (score 0):

It's an array so you should get the value via it's array index like so:

```
$course->courseinstances->start_end_date['startdate']
```